# Understanding this syntax if(obj[x])

Tags: javascript, foreach, indexof

So I'm following some tutorials on Udemy & on the whole they have been excellent except now there is a new instructor for the part I'm on now who isn't as descriptive on the inner workings of the functions.

The current example is a function that counts how many iterations of vowels there are within said string.

```
function vowelCount(str){
    var splitArr = str.toLowerCase().split("");
    var obj = {};
    var vowels = "aeiou";

    splitArr.forEach(function(letter){

        if(vowels.indexOf(letter) !== -1){
            if(obj[letter]){
                obj[letter]++;
            } else{
                obj[letter] = 1;
            }
        }
    });

}

vowelCount("abcdefghij")
```

The part that I'm personally stumped on is `if(obj[letter])`

In my mind the obj variable is empty and anything within the [] in this case is a reference to an index, and I don't understand what it is the if statement is checking I also don't really understand the syntax that follows of obj[letter].

Any enlightenment on this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: The condition is checking an index of an array/object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's doing this:

1. Evaluating `obj[letter]` (more on this part in [this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable)):

   - Evaluating `letter` to get its current value (for instance, `"a"`)
   - Evaluating `obj` to get its current value (the object)
   - Getting the value of the property named `"a"` (for instance) on the object; if the property doesn't exist, the result of that will be the value `undefined`
2. Branching into the `if` if the value from Step 1 is *truthy*

A *truthy* value is any value that isn't *falsy*. The falsy values are `undefined`, `null`, `0`, `""`, `NaN`, and of course, `false`.

Basically what that code is doing is seeing if `obj` already has a property for the letter and, if so, incrementing its value; if not, it's setting its value to 1.

Don't generalize that pattern too much, though. It works here because the property's value will never be `0` or `""` or similar (the values being stored start at 1 and only increase). But in other situations, if you need to see if a property exists on an object but its value may be one of those falsy values, use either `obj.hasOwnProperty(letter)` (to check if the property exists on the object itself, rather than its prototype), `letter in obj` if you want to check the object and its prototype chain, or if you want to be paranoid about `hasOwnProperty` being redefined use `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, letter)`. :-)

But this "falsy" check is very useful when you know the property will either not be there, or have a truthy value.

Comment: Thank you very much, this helped me to understand the concept, much appreciated :)